# PHP - Retrieve values of future dates from server

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to retrieve a list of all future dates that have been inserted into my MYSQL table.

Example: I have inserted the values 8-16-14, 8-27-16, 8-17-17. The issue is that the below code returns all of the values and not just the future ones.

Any ideas why this is not working?

```html
public function getUpcomingDate($id) {
   
$date = date('m-d-y');
  
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM roles WHERE id = ? AND item_date > '$date'");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
  $user = $stmt->get_result();
  $row_count = $user->num_rows;
  while ($row = $user->fetch_assoc()) {
   $data[] = $row;
  }

        $stmt->close();
  
  if($data) {
            return $data;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: MySQL might be expecting a specific format when comparing dates... Check out [str_to_date()](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php)